# Stack push and pop conceptual understanding

Tags: stack, puzzle

So, I'm working on a programming puzzle and need some help to see what I'm missing.

Here is the prompt:

> What are the contents of the stack after running the following algorithm?
>
> Given an array and an empty stack:
>
> 1. Push the values of the array onto the stack until a -1 value is found. Do not push the -1.
> 2. Pop the values in the stack until an even value is found or the stack is empty. The even value shouldn't be popped.
>
> Repeat steps 1 and 2 until the stack is full or the array is read completely.
>
> Type the contents of the stack from top to bottom, separated by a space, in the Answer box. If the stack is empty, enter a 0.
>
> For this problem, use an array = {10,1, 3, 2, 3, -1, 4, 5, 7}, and a stack size of 6.

I honestly feel like this should be pretty easy but for some reason I'm missing something and continue to get it wrong.

Here is my thought process: (stack from bottom to top)

1. 10 1 3 2 3
2. 10 1 3 2
3. 10 1 3 2 10 1
4. 10 1 3 2 10
5. 10 1 3 2 10 10

Final from top to bottom: 10 10 2 3 1 10

Is there something about stacks that I'm missing?
Any ideas?

Comment: The question wants you to *consume* the values in the array. Don't start over at the beginning of the array when you repeat step 1. You have already consumed `10` through `-1`, so you would go on to try to push `4`, `5`, and `7`.

Comment: Why do you have 4. and 5. in your list? The stack is full in step 3, which is a termination condition.

Comment: Oh! Okay. I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: Turns out the final answer was 5 4 2 3 1 10. I was going back to the beginning of the array rather than consuming the array values. Thanks for your time.